# Multiple headers in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP (5.3.26) to process a webhook, which requires an "Accepted" response.  So, this at the end of the file:

```
header ("HTTP/1.0 202");
echo ("Hello API Event Received");
```

So far so good.  But the webhook is sending a link to a PDF file which I need to GET and save.  I've always used this method for extracting pdfs (or other files):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$filename = "something";

header('Cache-Control: public'); 
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($response));
echo $response;
```

So, the problem that I can't get my head around is how to sequence these actions due to the multiple headers.  I've broken the pdf-processing code out into another file, but I can't call that file in a sub-routine, and I can't redirect to it because the redirect requires another header.  Obviously I could drop it in a queue to be processed by a cron job, but that seems a little hokey.

Any insights?

Comment: You say you want the webhook to send a link to a .pdf file, but your code sample is sending the .pdf file. Which do you actually want to do. 1) Send the pdf or 2) Send a link to the saved .pdf file????

Comment: Indeed. If you need to "GET and *save*" the PDF file, where exactly to you need to save it? Your code would send it back to the webhook, which presumably isn't what you want to do...

Comment: No.  Step 1: the webhook is another service and *provides* a link to the pdf.  I'm processing the webhook with code not shown here for brevity's sake.  The 202 response is back to the web service signifying acceptance.  Step 2: After getting the link "GET and save" would be used to retrieve and store the file on my server.

Comment: Yah, that's sort of what I'm saying. The code you've got would output the file to the client, in this case the web hook. Don't you just want to take your `$response` and save it on disk, rather than firing it back out? In which case, you just replace all those `header()` calls and the `echo()` with something like a `file_put_contents()`.